# PowerShell: cannot pipe output to file in combination with -Outputformat XML and -File

Tags: xml, powershell, output, command-line-interface

Script file `c:/chgpwd.ps1`

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $user,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $oldPass,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $newPass
)
write-host "before"
$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
([adsi]"WinNT://$Computername/$user").ChangePassword("$oldPass", "$newPass")
write-host "after"
```

When executing this via

```
powershell -OutputFormat XML -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File c:\chgpwd.ps1 'myuser' 'a' 'b' 2>&1 > C:\out.xml
```

Note: the user exists but its new password (b) does not match the password policy

the output file (C:\out.xml) won't contain any `xml`, but the `xml` will be shown in the console out.

For now I only get the content (out.xml)

> powershell : Exception calling "ChangePassword" with "2" argument(s): "The password does not meet the password policy 
>   requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.
>   "
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + powershell -OutputFormat XML -ExecutionPolicy bypass -File C:\chgpwd.ps1 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo> >   : NotSpecified: (:) [chgpwd.ps1], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI,chgpwd.ps1.ps1

Is there a way I get the xml ouput in the file?

Comment: What output do you expect? Why do you need xml?

Comment: I would have expected the xml which is rendered to the console out to be in the out file (if piped).
For parsing the error message xml would be better.

Answer (score 0):

i have not used the `-OutputFormat` switch before, but you may be able to use `export-clixml`

```
try {
    1/0
} catch {
    $_ | Export-Clixml C:\temp\text.xml
    start C:\temp\text.xml
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer:
I tried this and it works fine, but in case of a syntax error in the script this won't help or if a required parameter is missing or if it cannot find the file.

Especially in my case the script comes from third party.